# Пунктуация в предложении 1

Tags: пунктуация, стилистика

Помогите, пожалуйста, оформить это предложение в более гармоничное звучание, ну или хотя бы правильно расставить знаки препинания, если она здесь нужны.

*"Мы говорим "нет" некрасивым нагревательным элементам и их неуместному размещению в остальном привлекательной атмосфере помещения".*

Будет правильней написать "в остальном в привлекательной атмосфере"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

*...в остальном привлекательной атмосфере помещения...*

Очень некрасиво, придётся исправить фразу.

***Мы говорим "нет" некрасивым нагревательным элементам и их размещению в этом безукоризненно оформленном помещении.*** Тоже не идеально, но лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Мы говорим "нет" некрасивым нагревательным элементам и их неуместному размещению в этом в остальном привлекательном интерьере помещения.

Answer (score 0):

> Будут правильней написать "...в остальном в привлекательной атмосфере..

Нет, правильней не будет. Ваша фраза грамматически и пунктуационно верна, хотя очень тяжеловесна на слух.